# I did a survey for redesigning ATM machine's GUI and made the following GUI.How to make it more user-friendly for non-tech people?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, ux-field, novice-users

I did a quick survey and asked people what options they use mostly in ATM. Which changes do I require in the GUI?
Here are the screens that I redesigned for ATM after survey. Which changes should I do to make it more interactive, easy to use for non-tech persons and user-friendly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is too broad to answer properly. Is there a specific issue that you've identified?

Comment: The question is, what changes should I make in the GUI above to make it user-friendly for non-tech people?

Comment: I gathered that from your original post but it's a very broad question. Repeating it here doesn't make it any more specific. We can help you solve specific problems but can't enter into subjective discussions. Is there a specific problem that your users are reporting or that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If someone does not like my answer, please tell me why.**

So the example you are giving us is for atm's where you can withdraw money? I bet many people also deposit money or transfer it - But lets stick to withdrawing money.

Lets go from 1st to 2nd, top to bottom:

- What is the back button doing? Why is it there? Going back at an atm? (maybe only to change "Withdrawal" "Deposit" "Transfer" If it is for that I would change it to a List of options:

[image]

- Is the Picture an actual example or does the user have to put his thumb on the screen? (I understood it that he has to use the screen -> the box)
  If there is advice on the ATM to get the fingerprint: use an actual picture of the right thing.
- Make sure to use a big font size! Those screens are pretty small and old people can't read that good.
- The user does not know how much he withdraws! Let them know and put all the bills inside there. (Why double 1000? This confuses)
- Maybe even let the user input the amount he wants and show him what bills he gets and how much in total - I hate it if I withdraw 100 € and get only 10x10€.

[image]

Don't try to reinvent the wheel - take the old ATM UI as a reference and make it better.

Also I guess it should be a touch display? No buttons like on the "old" ones?

EDIT:

Here a "new" ATM UI from Austria with a touch screen:

[image]

Translated: Deposit - Withdraw - Quick - Something for Phone Credit

- A clean UI - with a Logo of the Company
- Different Colours for buttons (red to cancel)
- Simple buttons to navigate

Comment: I didn't vote you down (I don't do that unless an answer is demonstrably wrong or potentially damaging) but, because you asked, here's a guess at why someone might: from 2 screens you have inferred an entire system that may or may not exist, you've taken a simplified interface and made it much more complex, you make lots of assertions but don't give any evidence, the touchscreen example you gave has little relevance, and there are usability issues with the sketches you added. This question has been put on hold because it's impossible to give a measurably correct answer.